# Data props undefined on calling child component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am facing problem in passing data to my child component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import axios from 'axios'
import ClaimStatus from '../table/ClaimStatus'


export class ClaimsEW extends Component{

    render(){
        console.log(this.props.claim_approval_summary)
        return(
            <ScrollView>

                <View style={{elevation:5, backgroundColor:'#fff', margin:15}}>
                    <ClaimStatus newprops={this.props.claim_approval_summary} />
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}


class ClaimsAMC extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>
                    class two
                </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}



export default class ClaimsLevelTwo extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            id: '',
            param_oem: '',
            dropdown_arg: '',
            claim_approval_regions: [],
            claim_approval_summary: [],
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount(){

        const param_oem = this.props.navigation.getParam('value');
        const auth_id = this.props.navigation.getParam('auth_token');
        const dropdown_arg = this.props.navigation.getParam('arg');


        await this.setState({
            param_oem,
            id: auth_id,
            dropdown_arg,
            fetched: true
        });


        var headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'x-access-token',
            'x-access-token': this.state.id
        }

                axios.post('http://bi.servassure.net/api/ClaimApprovalSummary', {
                oem: this.state.param_oem,
            }, {headers:headers})
            .then(res => {

                let claim_approval_regions = res.data.region;
                let claim_approval_summary = res.data.data[0];



                this.setState({
                    claim_approval_regions :claim_approval_regions,
                    claim_approval_summary : claim_approval_summary
                });

                console.log(this.state.claim_approval_regions)
            }).catch(err => console.log(err));

    }
    render() {
        const state_values = this.state;
        console.log(state_values)
        return (
            (this.state.dropdown_arg === 'ew' ? (Object.keys(state_values).length > 0 ? <ClaimsEW {...state_values} /> : null) : <ClaimsAMC/>)
        )
    }
}
```

When I call `ClaimStatus newprops={this.props.claim_approval_summary} />` component inside the class `ClaimsEW`, the props gets undefined. I even tried printing the values without the new child component, giving just a  but still gives same result.

If I don't pass any new **Component** or **View** inside the class `ClaimsEW`, `console.log(this.props.claim_approval_summary)` prints the props value in console. On calling `ClaimStatus newprops={this.props.claim_approval_summary} />`, prints undefined props in following component.

The data I am receiving is in the object form hence I am converting it into array to map it further in the `<ClaimStatus/>` component.

Please help to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think cleaner code will solve your problems, i have cleaned out few parts of it maybe this will help

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import axios from 'axios'
import ClaimStatus from '../table/ClaimStatus'


export class ClaimsEW extends Component{
 render(){
    console.log(this.props.claim_approval_summary)
    return(
        <ScrollView>
            <View style={{elevation:5, backgroundColor:'#fff', margin:15}}>
                <ClaimStatus newprops={this.props.claim_approval_summary} />
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    )
 }
}


class ClaimsAMC extends Component{
 render(){
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>
                class two
            </Text>
        </View>
    )
 }
}



export default class ClaimsLevelTwo extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        id: '',
        param_oem: '',
        dropdown_arg: '',
        claim_approval_regions: [],
        claim_approval_summary: [],
    }
 }

 async componentDidMount(){
  const { getParam } = this.props.navigation;
  const param_oem = getParam('value');
  const auth_id = getParam('auth_token');
  const dropdown_arg = getParam('arg');

  const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'x-access-token',
        'x-access-token': auth_id
    };

    const result   =  await  axios.post('http://bi.servassure.net/api/ClaimApprovalSummary', {
            oem: param_oem,
        }, {headers:headers});


     const claim_approval_regions = res.data.region;
     const claim_approval_summary = res.data.data[0];

     this.setState({
          param_oem,
         id: auth_id,
            dropdown_arg,
            fetched: true,
             claim_approval_regions,
             claim_approval_summary,
        });


 }

 render() {
    const state_values = this.state;
   const { dropdown_arg } = state_values;
    return (
        // having dropdown_arg means the length is always > 0
        (dropdown_arg === 'ew' ? <ClaimsEW {...state_values} />) : <ClaimsAMC/>)
    )
 }
}
```

Comment: No luck. Still the same problem. As soon as `<ClaimStatus/>` is called, `newprops` become undefined.

Comment: Resolved it. I have to again apply object length condition for passing data props into child component. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

**Quick solution:** You need to call `this.props.newprops` like `console.log(this.props.newprops)` if you do `<ClaimStatus newprops={this.props.claim_approval_summary} />`

**Explanation:**

When you do this `<ClaimsEW {...state_values} />` you are basically sending each of the state values as a separate prop key. so this becomes `<ClaimsEW claim_approval_regions={[]} and so on... />` that's why `console.log(this.props.claim_approval_summary)` works when you do `<ClaimsEW {...state_values} />` . To understand this better I recommend you take a deep look at object destructuring feature of javascript.

One of the basic rule of sending prop is `<AnyComponent propOne={valueOne} propTwo={valueTwo} and so on.../>` and they become available in `AnyComponent` as `this.props.propOne`, `this.props.propTwo` and so on ...

Hope that helps. Cheers!

Comment: No luck. Still the same problem. As soon as `<ClaimStatus/>` is called, `newprops` become undefined.

Comment: Resolved it. I have to again apply object length condition for passing data props into child component. Thanks for help!